# Getting a PCI-E card and onboard video to work for a triple monitor display

Tags: display, pci, integrated-graphics, multiple-monitors

my computer: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883220026

I upgraded a few years back to a nvidia 9500 GT (isn't much, but it gets the job done)
I recently received a third monitor and was wondering if there was a way to use my onboard VGA to set it up. 
I heard I might have an issue with my bios (American Megatrends 0207 05/13/2009). 
Ive tried all of the bios options (IGD, PCI/IGD, PCI/PEG, PEG/IGD, and PEG/PCI) and have been unable to get all three screens to work at once. 
In my screen resolution settings, they all appear, but the one from the intel media accelerator (GMA x4500) is always grayed out, and when I switch to it, it will not appear and my other screen is shut off. 
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching same question.  My GeForce GT430 simply won't support 3 monitors simultaneously and my motherboard won't permit both onboard and PCI/PEG graphics display.  There is no easy way around this.  An inexpensive 3-monitor card is the solution or an additional graphics card.  Older systems could be "encouraged" into displaying three monitors, but newer ones can't be.
There are USB-DVI or VGA adapters but they're expensive and don't function nearly as fast as a graphics card.  They are basically a low-end graphics adapter built into the cable.
You can buy a DVI splitter which will spread one image onto two monitors, but this isn't same as three independent monitors.